# What is the male equivalent of 사모님?

Tags: vocabulary

When talking about the wife of your male teacher/boss/customer/etc, to show respect you would use the word 사모님. What is the male equivalent of this word? If you are respectfully trying to talk about the husband of your female teacher, for example, what is the word you would use? I have spent a good amount of time googling for this but I haven't got anywhere, and can't even find something to start.

Answer (score 1):

There is '부군 (夫君)', which is a formal word to mention one's husband with respect. The word '남편분 (남편 + -분)' is also used in casual conversations.

e.g. "부군께서는 어떤 일을 하십니까?"

Comment: Then would just saying 남편님 sound natural?

Comment: 부군 is standard but I think it's somewhat old-fashioned. It might be appropriate in very formal occasions (e.g., giving a public speech); otherwise I'd recommend 남편분. (Also, I don't think 남편님 works. It sounds weird to me.)